# Does Hörmander's condition imply smooth density of transition probabilities conditioned on non-blow-up?

Tags: pr.probability, operator-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

**Motivation.** I’m not an expert on stochastic calculus and stochastic differential equations; I often see the Fokker-Planck equations and Hörmander's theorem formulated as addressing “transition probabilities”, but without any reference to the case that there is a positive probability of blow-up in finite time. It is this case that I am interested in. There are probably several questions that one could ask in this regard, but for the moment I will stick with the below.

---

Let $M$ be a $C^\infty$ smooth manifold, let $b,\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ be $C^\infty$ vector fields on $M$, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the smallest Lie algebra that both contains $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ and is closed under $f \mapsto [f,b]$.

Consider the Stratonovich SDE
$$ dX_t = b(X_t) dt + \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(X_t) \circ dW_t^i $$
where $(W_t^1,\ldots,W_t^n)$ is an $n$-dimensional Wiener process. Fix a non-empty open set $U \subset M$, and for each $x \in U$ and $t > 0$, let $E_{t,x,U}$ be the event that the SDE has a strong solution $(X_s^x)_{s \in [0,t]}$ starting at $X_0^x=x$ with $\{X_s^x:s \in [0,t]\} \subset U$.

> > Suppose that for all $x \in U$, $\{f(x):f \in \mathcal{L}\}=T_xM$. Does it follow that for all $x \in U$ and $t > 0$, the finite measure $\nu_{t,x,U}$ given by
> > $$ \nu_{t,x,U}(A) = \mathbb{P}(E_{t,x,U} \cap \{X_t^x \in A\}) $$
> > is Lebesgue-absolutely continuous with a density that is $C^\infty$ on $U$?

Comment: Would I be right that someone has downvoted my question? I’m curious to know what the reason might be.

Comment: I think if you have enough reputation, you can see the number of upvotes and downvotes (I don't have enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, one can work on open domains (to account for blow-ups as you mention) but once again one again needs bounded smooth coefficients and non-degeneracy for the volatility coefficients:  in the work "Smoothness and asymptotic estimates of densities for SDEs with locally smooth coefficients and applications to square root-type diffusions." they obtain local results

> The aim of this paper is to relax the aforementioned conditions on the
> coefficients: roughly speaking, we assume that the coefficients are smooth
> only on an open domain D and have bounded partial derivatives therein.
> Moreover, we assume that the nondegeneracy condition on the diffusion
> coefficient holds true on D only. Under these assumptions, we prove that
> the law of a strong solution to the equation admits a smooth density on D
> (Theorem 2.1). Furthermore, when D is the complementary of a compact
> ball and the coefficients satisfy some additional assumptions on D (mainly
> dealing with their growth and the one of derivatives), we give upper bounds
> for the density for large values of the state variable (Theorem 2.2). We
> will occasionally refer to these aymptotic estimates of the density as “tail
> estimates” or estimates on the density’s “tails.”

[image]